# Laravel booking system design

Tags: php, laravel, database-design, eloquent

I want to create a booking system in Laravel where user chooses Date and one of the timeslots given. My idea right now is to store in database table (MySQL), the booking_date in one field and the booking_timeslot in another. The problem with this design is that I do not know how to prevent another user from choosing the same date and timeslot, or how to render the timeslot chosen on a particular day non-usable again.

Please I would really appreciate any advice. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a specific language you're thinking about writing this booking system in? If so please ammend that to your question and I'll do my best to help :). Otherwise there are plenty of languages to choose from like PHP, Django (Python) or even Javascript for database entry management and validation.  You'd probably want to handle that in the database validation step. Although the people on [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) might be able to help you better.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am using Laravel (so PHP) in this case and I am not sure how to make sure the user does not select the same timeslot on the same day. I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: And I assume you're using MySQL as well?

Comment: Yes that's correct!

Comment: You’ll need to show all existing booking dates on your front end and disable those individual dates on the input calendar. That should cover most users, but for the ones who like to push the limits, you should also use a validation function on the backend to check whether the date and time submitted is already booked.

Comment: @Savlon, how do I get rid of timeslots of a particular date after they have been chosen by other users.

Comment: @michelle85201 you pass the dates and times from your backend to your front end and disable those in the calendar input you’re using. So you conduct a database query for all allocated dates and times. Pass those details to your view. Disable those dates in your calendar input. Let the user choose which date and time they want. Post those results to the backend where a validator double checks they aren’t already allocated.

Comment: @Savlon thank you very much! At the moment I am using a simple <input type="date"> for the user to input the date, would you happen to know a calendar input I can use?

Comment: Yeh I would definitely use something other than the basic date input. As for what that would be, I’m not sure of any but a google search should give you a few. I don’t use blade templates for my apps, I use vuejs components and there are a bunch of calendar-like components for that... but I wouldn’t recommend you use vuejs until you’ve grasped the concept of everything. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to achieve your goal but one interesting way is generating all booking with dates and 24 hours in one table with blank order id and when order come reserve them with order id